# Is the answer wrong? (Introduction to Probability Models 11th Edition)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

In the exercises of Chapter 4, the ninth problem says that

> In a sequence of independent flips of a fair coin that comes up heads with probability .6, what is the probability that there is a run of three consecutive heads within the first 10 flips?

Here I define the state variable $X_n$ to represent the number of heads that have come up at the $n_{th}$ toss, so the process $\{X_n, n\geq 0\}$ is a Markov Chain with states set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and its transition probability matrix is

$P = \left[\begin{matrix}
0.4 & 0.6 & 0 & 0 \\
0.4 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 \\
0.4 & 0 & 0 & 0.6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]$

So the answer should be $P_{0,3}^{10} = 0.7014$, but the answer given in the book is $0.5078$. So is this answer wrong or did I construct the wrong transition probability matrix?

Comment: I haven't checked it, but the phrase "**fair** coin that comes up heads with probability $.6$" sends up red flags for me.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Good call! I think this is the problem. The same approach with probabilities of $0.5$ gives $0.5078$ as the answer.

Comment: I have checked the situation of fair coin and the answer is 0.5078!

Comment: Side note: $X_n$ here represents something other than the number of heads. It is $3$ if there were ever three heads in a row and otherwise the number of *current* consecutive heads.